# Unity object not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a sort of movement system for an enemy, but the enemy just doesn't move. It's locked dead in place. Here is the code segments in which it's meant to move:

```cs
[SerializeField] float speed;
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
if (attack2cooldown < 0)
{
    transform.LookAt(playertarget);
                        
    Dash_Attack();
    attack2cooldown = attack2CD;
}

IEnumerator Dash_Attack()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, TheEnemyItselfLol.transform.position);
    Vector3 b = playertarget.position;

    while (distance > 3)
    {
        Vector3 a = transform.position;
        controller.Move(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.DeltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

and

```cs
controller.Move(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In case the player is out of range.
I have added certain checks to see if range and cooldowns work properly and they do. So the issue is that the object straight up doesn't move.
Here is the entire code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
public class SwordWielder : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float angle = 10;
    public float t;
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
    [SerializeField] protected int damage;
    [SerializeField] protected int health;
    [SerializeField] protected GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] protected Transform playertarget;
    bool dead = false;
    [SerializeField] Animator weapon;
    [SerializeField] Animator BottomCube;
    [SerializeField] Animator Hand;
    [SerializeField] GameObject TheEnemyItselfLol;
    [SerializeField] float attack1dist;
    [SerializeField] float attack1CD;
    float attack1cooldown = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField] float attack2dist;

    [SerializeField] float attack2CD;
    float attack2cooldown = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 direction;
    float distance;

    public void OnDeath()
    {
        dead = true;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("dead", true);
        GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
    }

    void Start()
    {
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!dead)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, TheEnemyItselfLol.transform.position);
            
                if (distance < attack1dist)
                {
                    if (attack1cooldown < 0)
                    {
                        transform.LookAt(playertarget);
                        weapon.SetTrigger("attack");
                        attack1cooldown = attack1CD;

                    }
                }

                else if (distance < attack2dist)
                {
                    if (attack2cooldown < 0)
                    {
                        transform.LookAt(playertarget);
                        weapon.SetTrigger("JETSTREAMSAM");
                        Hand.SetTrigger("JETSTREAMSAM");
                        Dash_Attack();
                        attack2cooldown = attack2CD;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    controller.Move(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            
            transform.LookAt(playertarget);
            print(distance);
            attack1cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
            attack2cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
            print(attack1cooldown);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Dash_Attack()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, TheEnemyItselfLol.transform.position);
        Vector3 b = playertarget.position;

        while (distance > 3)
        {
            Vector3 a = transform.position;
            controller.Move(Vector3.MoveTowards(a, b, speed));
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that a lot of the variables aren't used, those are from solutions to other problems that ended up not working. I didn't clean the code up yet.

Comment: Please provide the code in the correct format...

Comment: Im not sure what the correct format is so I will just add the entire code separately.

Comment: Did you actually set a speed for your character? Ensure it is not 0

Comment: I did set the speed

Comment: Did you check if your enemy gameobject is marked as Static or not?

Comment: It isn't marked as static.